# How to migrate Applications in Azure Active Directory to another Tenant

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD tenant, in this tenant, I have registered a number of applications for SSO purposes. Now I need to migrate these to a new Azure AD tenant as the workload is moving to a new tenant. Is it possible to move all the applications registered in the Azure AD to a new AAD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an application in any AAD tenant you like, even if it is published in a resource group located in a separate AD. To move the registration to a new AD all you need to do is delete the app registration under the old tenant and create a new application in the new tenant.

Comment: What if you want to keep the same app ID and not have to recreate all the service principles created in different tenants? The app could be actively in USE but for example the old tenant has been retired for whatever reason and the app needs to move to new tenant / ownership. You don't want to disturb all the existing users if you can help it.